# In menu not able to nest items to group widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout, menu

neither nesting nor movement of menuItems and groups up and down wrt each other is  taking place. 
Android Studio version - 2.3.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mikCB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code you can use,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.akshaymanagooli.adggbtbrt.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="items"
    app:showAsAction="never" >
    <menu>
        <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="item 1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="item 2"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

So idea is inside an item create a new menu block and add your sub items in there so it'll show you a arrow mark like dropdown thing.

Comment: just open the text tab and you can do these changes.

Comment: Why it is not possible through component tree, without using xml? I am new to android development .

Comment: I am also still learning but , dont get addicted to drag and drop, best way is to do in text coz you will have more control

Comment: Okay ! Thanks Man ! When did you start android development?

Comment: about 3 months ago